# PHP Retrieve DATA from XML

Tags: php, xml

My first attempt at retrieving data from XML for a maps application has failed. Here is a piece of the XML Feed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DirectionsResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <route>
  <leg>

   <start_address>Winkfield, Bracknell, Berkshire RG42 6LY, UK</start_address>
   <end_address>Wentworth, Surrey GU25 4, UK</end_address>

  </leg>
 </route>
</DirectionsResponse>
```

I want to get the start and end address and return them via AJAX to the application.

The PHP

```
<?php 

$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='.$start.'&destination='.$end.'&sensor=false');


// data to fetch

$start = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/start_address");

$end = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/end_address");

$start = array($start);
// output

echo json_encode( array('output'=>$start[0]));


?>
```

Annoyingly this is returning an object to the page.

Response :: `{"output":[{"0":"Winkfield, Windsor, Berkshire SL4 2ES, UK"}]}`

Anyone know how to stop that from happening. I just want the value Winkfield, Windsor, Berkshire SL4 2ES, UK.

Comment: can you show the print_r of $start;

Comment: do it by hand. E.g. `echo "{ 'output' : { 'start' : '$start', 'end' : '$end' } }";`

Comment: I think he means that he wants to end up with `{"output":"Winkfield, Windsor, Berkshire SL4 2ES, UK"}`

Comment: @Mick Hansen I guess, he doesn't need this "0"

Comment: @Nemoden Probably, but i think he's missed the part in the SimpleXML XPath documentation about XPath returning an array of elements - That's why he's getting the list output in JSON.

Comment: Yes. And I think it's more convenient to get `start_address` and `end_address` by `$start = $xml->route->leg->start_address` and `$end = $xml->route->leg->end_address` and then just `json_encode( compact('start', 'end') );` XPath would be more suitable if we need more complicated traversion of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested your specific case, but i remember running into something similar when using SimpleXML, you might want to use (string) to cast it out of the object

```
array('output'=> (string)$start[0])
```

Or rather just leave out $start = array($start) and just do

```
array('output'=> (string)$start)
```

On reading the SimpleXML XPath documentation (http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) again i think your problem might be this:

```
Returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects or FALSE in case of an error.
```

So the XPath returns an array, then you wrap that in an array and take the first element of that array, so all you end up with is the original array - remove the array wrap and you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

```
function XMLReader()
{
    $MyArray = array();

    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    $doc->load( 'XMLFilePath.xml' ); 
    $info = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "leg" );
    foreach( $info as $Type )
    {
        $details = $Type->getElementsByTagName( "start_address" );
        $detail = $details->item(0)->nodeValue;     
        $MyArray [] = $detail; 
    }

    return $MyArray;
}
```

and same for end_Address.
I wish this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $xml->route->leg->start_address;
```

This is the edited answer. I checked it. Its working properly on the XML.

Comment: Use this code just after loading the xml file. you dont need the XPATH lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just echo $start? Also, why do you make an array of start and then output the first element, it doesnt make any sense at all.